# When concatenating strings to put together a new DOM element with Javascript, it only takes the first whitespace separated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following code

```
var aVar = "sample text";
alert(aVar);
$(this).replaceWith( "<input type='text' value=" + aVar + " id='laID' style='width: 100px; padding-right:20px; color:white;'/>");
```

The alert message box returns the expected value: "sample text". However, the DOM element is generated with the following value: "sample". Now, if i try it the following way it works:

```
$(this).replaceWith( "<input type='text' value='sample text' id='laID' style='width: 100px; padding-right:20px; color:white;'/>");
```

Unfortunately, i have no choice but to read the value from a variable, i can't have it hardcoded. Hope someone can guide me with this! thankss

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CHange:

```
value=" + aVar + " id='
```

To:

```
value='" + aVar + "' id='
```

Attributes should be quoted.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing quotation marks. Use this:

```
$(this).replaceWith( "<input type='text' value='" + aVar + "' id='laID' style='width: 100px; padding-right:20px; color:white;'/>");
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't string quoted the value of the `value` attribute in your first example.
It should be written:

```
$(this).replaceWith( "<input type='text' value='" + aVar + "' id='laID' style='width: 100px; padding-right:20px; color:white;'/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone have already answered your question, but... when you get stuck with string bugs like that, just use an "alert" to see the evaluated string.
This would save you time:

```
alert( "<input type='text' value=" + aVar + " id='laID' style='width: 100px; padding-right:20px; color:white;'/>");
```